# Retrieve data table cell values to select option box

Tags: javascript, json, datatables, jquery-select2

I am trying to retrieve data table cell values to input and select option boxes. The values are displaying in the input box but it fails to display in option select box.

```
$("#txt_UserName").val(table.cell('.row-modified', 3).data()); 
$("#dd_Country").select2(“val”, table.cell('.row-modified', 2).data());
```

Answer (score 0):

Selects don't have value properties.  You need to find the matching option element underneath the select and set its `selected` property (while ensuring all other options do not have `selected` set).